# Assigning vector as value to key in std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to assign a `vector` as value to keys in `unorderd_map`.

```
int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<int,std::vector<int>> a1;
    std::vector<int> t1 = {10}; 
    a1[1]=t1; //question
    a1[1].push_back(11);
    a1[1].push_back(12);
   // ....        
   // ....
}
```

In my case, I first want to assign `t1` to a key and then add values to the vector `a1[1]`. Instead of defining `t1`, how can I assign a vector on the fly? Something like `a1[1] = std::vector<int> {10}` ? Do I have to define a temporary variable, `t1` in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vectors can be assigned with an initializer list.

```
a1[1] = {10, 11, 12};
```